# Post Feedback Breakdown hover text is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, tooltips

> **Note**: post feedback page [has been removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209787/152859) and will no longer be available

I noticed on the [Christianity Post Feedback](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback) page:

> [image]

Clearly the hover text *ought* to read:

> received 4 to 10 feedback votes.

**N.B.:** You need [this privilege](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) to see the page.

Comment: I hate these hints at cool stuff I can't see. :)

Comment: @vasco: You might want to try out some of the beta sites where the bar to entry is much lower.  If you [find a site](http://stackexchange.com/sites#newest) you are interested in, of course...

Comment: I've joined a [few](http://stackexchange.com/users/74033/vascowhite?tab=accounts), but I always end up back at SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errrr yeah, guess that should be correct and such, fixed in the next build.