# Post Feedback link is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, post-feedback

I first noticed this a while back. But it has yet to resolve itself.

When I click on the [post feedback link](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback) in the 10k tools, it hangs for a while.
Then it gives me an error message:

[image]
[image]

Comment: `This page requires more privileges` from my side. So, can't know, but kinda *did work for me*.

Comment: You're right. I tried visiting the link while logged out. It gave me the correct message: "This page requires more privileges"

Comment: Maybe try a different browser? Just to verify it's not just *your problem* since no one else seems to be commenting for verification.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil I get the error message while logged in on both Firefox and Chrome. Both at work and at home.

Comment: The link works on both Meta.SO and Space.SE. Sounds isolated to SO.

Comment: @Undo You're right. It works on MSO and Anime.SE for me. Just not on SO.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It only took [a little over 5 years for me to get around to fixing this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209655/post-feedback-link-is-broken#comment672356_209787), but this link has been put back under `/tools` and the page should be loading again.

[image]

I spent a bit of time yesterday looking at the Post Feedback page and tried to optimize the queries. After refactoring things a bit, the query now runs in about 10 seconds versus the original 30-40 seconds that resulted in the time-out on that page. I'll monitor the performance on Stack Overflow and see if I need to make any more changes to help that page along.

Answer (score 11):

The way this is architected absolutely does not scale.  It's also not something we want to put resources into fixing given opportunity cost and what it would take to refactor.

We will be removing the link in the next build and removing the page and code later in the week.  I'm sorry that answer sucks, but it's just not an important feature to us, and it would take a significant time investment to fix.

Comment: Removing it from SO only or all sites?

Comment: @3ventic likely all sites, it's a fairly significant database pain point (seriously, pivot tables) that has grown large enough to be an issue now.

Comment: That's a sour pill to swallow. Any chance for other bonus to 10K users instead?

Comment: Are you taking away *all* the anonymous and low rep feedback (which is a good source of indication that random people from google are or are not finding what they are looking for when they hit a given question)? or just this interface to it (and redesigning said interface at some point in the not-determined future... like just showing it on the questions and answers themselves)?

Comment: I'd like to see the anon feedback for a single post. Probably just up/downvotes, like the score.

Comment: @NickCraver pivot tables you say, I love [pivots](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pivot/topusers). :)  I'll work on it.

Comment: @NickCraver I hope this isn't being removed entirely... I've left many a comment saying "you can click the helpful/not helpful" links.

Comment: @NickCraver But seriously, I am willing to try to fix the page instead of removing it.

Comment: @bluefeet it's a backend database performance problem, not something easily solved.  We *can* solve anything, but we have limited hours available and must prioritize things.

Comment: @nhinkle just the page, not the links - it's the aggregation queries that would need an overhaul caching, syncing, etc. that we're not willing to put the effort into.

Comment: Your answer sucks!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ....... have an upvote.

Comment: Huh... I think this is the first time I've even heard of this feature, even though I've had 10k on SO for almost a year. Kind of sad, really, I would've liked to see it while it still existed. :( At least this (kind of) answers another question I've had for a long time, namely "is that anonymous feedback data actually used for anything, or does it just go straight into the bit bucket?"

Comment: Now that link works fine. Is this by design?

Comment: The page is still around [for stack overflow at least](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback/summary?filter=day) - however, there are no links to it from the 10k tools page

Comment: @NickCraver it's been nearly 5 years, and the code is still there. But your answer [causes feature-requests related to Post-Feedback to be closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122699/provide-a-questions-only-filter-for-the-post-feedback-tool). So, could you either update your answer and clarify that you'll keep the code (as a hidden feature, like /timeline), or either give a final coup-de-grace to this page and actually kill the availability of it to 10k users?

Comment: @ NickCraver I'll second @Cœur on that ping.

Answer (score 4):

This link still finely works anywhere, except Stack Overflow.

So, whatever reasons were to [disable it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209787), the page is still accessible there on any Stack site (works on beta site for me; confirmed to work on Meta; for me on other sites excluding SO (which gives "not found") and LH (which fully works, because I have required rep there) the page says "more privileges required").