# Is the count of anonymous feedback available in the schema?

Tags: support, data-explorer, post-feedback, anonymous-visitors

I've been interested in what sort of questions are helpful to anonymous people rather than regulars. I would like to get a count of [anonymous feedback "Helpful" and "Not Helpful" votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing) on a question.

I cannot see how that information is available through the [schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

I am not sure if I am simply missing something staring at me in the face, or whether the Stack Exchange team have [decided it isn't worth sharing this information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209655/post-feedback-link-is-broken/209787#209787). (Or another alternative I haven't considered!)

How do you fetch a count of anonymous feedback helpful votes on a post through the Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's in the `PostFeedback` table, where an up vote (`VoteTypeId = 2`) corresponds to helpful, and a down vote (`VoteTypeId = 3`) is not helpful.

So for a given post `##PostId##`, [the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/205128) becomes something like

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 2 THEN 1 END) AS HelpfulVotes,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN VoteTypeId = 3 THEN 1 END) AS NotHelpfulVotes
FROM PostFeedback
WHERE PostId = ##PostId##
GROUP BY PostId
```

You may want to add a where clause in there to filter on `IsAnonymous` too, depending on whether you care to exclude registered users who can't vote or not from the totals.

Comment: Ah, according to the VoteType table, these are "UpMod" and "DownMod" votes. The bit that I failed to comprehend while looking was that they have nothing to do with Moderators. Thanks.