# Are attempts at voting on locked posts recorded anywhere?

Tags: support, voting, data-explorer, locked

Like anonymous feedback, where SE gathers data about unregistered users voting on normal posts, is the same done for locked posts, and is this information stored on SEDE?

Comment: Well, there is request sent to the server (and response with error message) so on the very least, it's recorded in the raw traffic logs.

Comment: Would this help: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/242834/anonymous-votes-and-views-log-view

Comment: @HackerKarma how? I already know of anonymous feedback, but I'm not sure if they get registered on locked post or how...

Comment: @Braiam I agree with what ShadowWizard said above. What we don't know or what SEDE may not offer us is to query the server log. But, SE team can do it for sure.

Comment: @HackerKarma of course they can, that's why it is tagged support

Comment: @Braiam yep and you got my +1. I am eager to know the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, well not for logged-in users that would otherwise have the privilege to vote. The request is (as Shadow Wizard noted in comments) logged and queryable to some extent, but there's no 'feedback' if you're registered.

If you're unregistered or not logged in, it is recorded, [you can try voting on this while incognito](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454), the feedback is sent.

Comment: I just did an up-vote in incognito mode and yes the feedback is sent but where did it go? In the server log or in the database? The reason for asking is OP wants to know "if this information stored on SEDE" and can we make a query against.

Comment: @HackerKarma Anonymous/low-rep feedback is [available through SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234829), and I'm pretty sure Braiam knew that; he was interested specifically in vote attempts on locked posts.

Comment: Good, I was worried that that feedback was lost due the post being locked.

Comment: @NormalHuman when I said "I just did an up-vote in incognito mode" I wa referring to Tim Post's "you can try voting on this while incognito"... In other words, I up-voted the 'closed' post and then wanted to know where did it go. In the server log or in the database?