# Is the /tools/post-feedback page removed?

Tags: support, voting, 10k-tools, anonymous-visitors

It's mentioned in [Post Feedback link is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209655/post-feedback-link-is-broken/209787#209787) that the /tools/post-feedback page is removed for 10k users.

And it doesn't show up in Links:

[image]

However, the page seems to be still up and running when navigated there manually.

Comment: Yeah, "later this week" sometimes means "at some point in the future, maybe few years, when someone will poke us."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not yet since I can still see [it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback):

[image]

The link is probably gone since they are probably like halfway through the removal process. Of course, this page will be completely removed but in some time in the future. Shadow Wizard said it best:

> Yeah, "later this week" sometimes means "at some point in the future, maybe few years, when someone will poke us."