# Accidentally downvoted in an exchange I don't have 125 reputation on

Tags: support, reputation, voting, down-votes

On occasion I will accidentally click the downvote button in an exchange I don't have 125 reputation on. As the pop-up says, nothing public happens, but the downvote is still recorded. Is there a way to "unrecord" the downvote? I've been upvoting then removing my upvote in the hopes an upvote still clears a downvote for sub-125 users, but I have no idea if this is actually working. Do recorded downvotes from sub-125 users even matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It wouldn't really matter even if you did downvote without the privilege (and give negative 'post feedback'). The post feedback just gets stored in a table in the database, and isn't actually used for anything meaningful. It will not:

- change the post score
- affect anyone's reputation
- convert into a 'real' downvote even if you pass 125 rep.

I don't know of a way to reverse your post feedback, but I don't think it's really a necessary feature, as very few people even know the data exists, let alone use it for anything meaningful. It's only really visible from [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) or the post feedback statistics in the 10k moderator tools.

Comment: It still exists in the 10k tools but there is [no link to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289192/307988) so I doubt many even see it any more