# What happened to "anonymous user feedback"?

Tags: discussion, unregistered-users, anonymous, post-feedback

What happened to [Anonymous user feedback now in testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing)?

Now when I visit a Stack Exchange site as an anonymous user, I can't find a feedback button. Where did it go?

Comment: It's just the up/down vote buttons. I just voted this page anonymously and pressed downvote and it said thanks for the feedback but didn't change the post score, but now back at my logged in session it does change it.

Comment: @PeterJ did you checked the linked question? It is talking about something you see in the dev page of google and microsoft

Comment: @Error I did but how does it relate to Google/MS? I thought the separate button was removed ages ago and just replaced with the normal vote buttons.

Comment: yes. That's the answer

Answer (score 6):

According to [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) the way that works was changed on 2013-02-11:

- If a visitor is not logged in or doesn't have enough reputation to vote, the vote system redirects the vote to the anonymous feedback system, and shows a [small blue dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u1a7.png).

So you just press the normal up / down vote buttons to provide anonymous feedback although it now appears as follows:

[image: Anonymous feedback]

Answer (score 3):

The 'feedback' button shown in that post doesn't exist anymore.

The [Anonymous post feedback](/questions/tagged/post-feedback) that was collected through that button is now collected through the regular vote buttons. Logged-in users without voting privileges will see a message saying that the vote is recorded but not displayed publicly, logged-out visitors just see a message prompting them to sign up or log in...

The data is available as part of the 10k tools at /tools/post-feedback, although [the link has been removed and some of the data is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289192/307988) so I'm not sure if it's maintained and/or reliable.

See [Once I reach 15 reputation, will my old votes be taken into account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285181/307988)