# "You must be logged in to vote" bug/glitch

Tags: bug, voting, login, error-message

As you can see in the below image, I got a pop-up telling me to log in to vote, yet I was logged in. Reloading the page seemed to have worked but I was wondering if this minor glitch could be fixed? It has happened to me several times.

[image]

Comment: It briefly came up, but then disappeared when I upvoted.

Comment: @Ollie What do you mean? It won't let you upvote during the glitch, every time you try, the message pops up.

Comment: I upvoted, the error came up, then I clicked again and it worked.  Can't see an error now.

Comment: Hmmm. I haven't encountered that yet.

Comment: Even if [not logged in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299717/282094) anonymous [post feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-feedback) should show a different message; something's off.

Comment: I tried reproducing this error and wasn't able to. Is this still an issue people are running into? Can others still reproduce this error?

Comment: @Rosie haven't seen it since that brief glitch.