# Is there a way to tell if a question has had a sudden increase in page views?

Tags: support, questions, views

Other than taking a record of the page views over time, is there any way to tell if a question has received a sudden increase in page views?

The reason I am interested is it could be a useful indicator of a problem with some software (e.g. a new release could be causing an old issue to reemerge).

Answer (score 6):

Some options:

- Search for snapshots of the question in the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/). The tooltip showing the exact number of views (instead of e.g. '10k views') fortunately still works. Note that if the question title changes, the URL changes as well, so you might need a wildcard search.
- You can check [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for the number of views as of the previous Sunday morning.
- If that is not far back enough, there's a [quarterly data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19579/295232).

Related question: [Is there a way to determine how/why when one of my posts on a network site suddenly starts getting unusual traction?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340064/295232)

Comment: Thanks very much. I never thought of using WBM, that's very resourceful. And I didn't even know SEDE provided page views.

Comment: I'd write a query for you but a) it's a nice exercise and b) I have a conference call in a few minutes. See the [documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/2952320) for some pointers.

Comment: @stevec, the [history of views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92554/282094) is not retained at Stack Exchange. The history of votes and entry to HNQ is recorded by date and time; one could take the current views and total up/down votes and create a vote-per-view number (two, for up and down) and then presume that as the votes came in they were the result of a certain number of views. While the method is off the average is not bad, and it permits a direct query to be derived and applied to many questions rather than manually searching Wayback or writing your own code to examine the dumps.

Comment: @stevec (and Glorfindel, if you want to tweak this), here is a [Q&A for 'votes over time, versus edits'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148466/282094). You can see the jumps in the votes, but people who view might not vote. --- The total up & down votes (after modifying that query) would **loosely** track the views. A sharp uptick (not related to entering the HNQ, or a bump from an edit) would indicate views on a particular day ***if*** the viewers voted. There's also [post-feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289206/282094)'s low rep. votes, but I don't know if SEDE dates those.